# Testing null in ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I'd like display `payment.invoice.reference` when `invoice` is not null.

I tried this :

```
<tr *ngFor="let payment of payments; index as i">
  <td>
    <span *ngIf="payment.invoice">{{payment.invoice.reference}}</span>
    <span *ngIf="!payment.invoice">Notinh</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I tried this :

```
<tr *ngFor="let payment of payments; index as i">
  <td>{{payment?.invoice.reference}}</td>
</tr>
```

But that's not work.

Any idea ?

Comment: add ? after invoice, too: {{payment?.invoice?.reference}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already doing it on the payment ? , its the same thing you need to add after invoice. It is called as safe navigation operator,

```
 <td>{{payment?.invoice?.reference}}</td>
```

Alternatively you could use ***`ngIf`** directive as well

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you are not dealing with observables, so I quess it is a kind of Array of Interfaces or Arrays. I really can't understand how your data is structured by the information provided , but I will give you an idea how you should deal with *ngIf and what it thinks is valid ( not dealing with Observables , Subjects and other rxjs stuff here ) : 
Tested and works . This only shows the reference 4 ( as all the rest invoices are not valid for *ngIf ) . 
This is a showcase, so you should adapt your code corresponding to your data source.
**Your 'payments.component.ts ' :**

```
export class PaymentsListComponent {
  payments : Array<Payments> = new Array<Payments>();  
  constructor() {
    this.payments.push(new Payments(null , 1)); 
    this.payments.push(new Payments(undefined, 2)); 
    this.payments.push(new Payments (NaN,3)) ; 
    this.payments.push(new Payments("I am a real invoice", 4 ));
  }

}


export class Payments { 
  constructor(inv, ref) {
    this.invoice = inv ; 
    this.reference = ref; 
  }
  invoice  ; 
  reference ; 
}
```

**Your 'payments.component.html' :**

```
<tr *ngFor="let payment of payments">
  <td>
    <span *ngIf="payment.invoice">{{payment.reference}}</span>

  </td>
</tr>
```

This, as I said, will output only the 4th invoice ( which is not : Null , NaN or undefinded ) . Hope this helps .